# How to query a composite id key inside a list

Tags: c#, nhibernate

How can I query a composite key field in a multiple IN clause SQL?

My Subsidiary is a composite of a String and a Company

```cs
public class Company
{
     public virtual String Id { get; set; }
}

public class Subsidiary
{
     public virtual String Id { get; set; }
     public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class Disponibility
{
     public virtual String IdCompany { get; set; }
     public virtual String IdSubsidiary { get; set; }
}
```

Currently stuck at this

```cs
var subsidiarys = session.Query<Subsidiary>().ToList();
var result = session.Query<Disponibility>().Where(x => subsidiarys.Contains(???) ).ToList();
```

The generated query needs to be

```sql
SELECT * FROM VW_DISPONIBILITY D
WHERE (D.COMPANY, D.SUBSIDIARY) IN (SELECT S.COMPANY, S.SUBSIDIARY FROM SUBSIDIARY S);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all databases support oracle multiple IN clause so the only way to do this is by concatenating multiples `or`.

```
var disjunctions = Restrictions.Disjunction();
foreach (var sub in subsidiarys)
{
    disjunctions.Add(Restrictions.Where<Disponibility>(x => x.IdCompany == sub.Company.Id && x.IdSubsidiary == sub.Id));
}

var result = session.QueryOver<Disponibility>()
                    .Where(disjunctions)
                    .List<Disponibility>();
```

Generated SQL

```sql
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    VW_DISPONIBILITY this_ 
WHERE
    (
        (
            this_.COMPANY = :p0 
            and this_.SUBSIDIARY = :p1
        ) 
        or (
            this_.COMPANY = :p2 
            and this_.SUBSIDIARY = :p3
        )
        ...
    );
```